# How to change legend shapes in R using ggplot and scale_colour_brewer()

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the small example below I've managed to get my plot to look like I would like to, except for getting the right shapes in the legend. Any help, please?

Without `guides(shape='none')` I am getting two legends, one with colours, and another with shapes. How can they be combined?

```
require(ggplot2)

dat = data.frame(
    Type      = c('T1', 'T1', 'T2', 'T2', 'T3', 'T3'),
    Condition = c('C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2'),
    Estimate  = c(12.9, 13.4, 13.1, 13.6, 13.1, 13.8),
    lo95CI    = c(12.0, 12.5, 12.2, 12.7, 12.1, 12.8),
    hi95CI    = c(14.0, 14.5, 14.2, 14.7, 14.1, 14.8),
    Data      = c(0.9, 1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 2.9, 3.1)
)

p1 <- ggplot(data=dat,
    aes(x=Data, y=Estimate, group=Condition)) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(11,15)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape=Condition, colour=Condition), size=3) +
    geom_errorbar(width=.12, linewidth=.5,
        aes(ymin=lo95CI, ymax=hi95CI, colour=Condition)) +
    scale_colour_brewer('Task:', palette='Dark2') +
    scale_x_continuous('Stimulus Type',
        breaks=c(1, 2, 3, 4),
        labels=c('T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4')) +
    scale_y_continuous('DV') +
    guides(shape='none') +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14),
        legend.text=element_text(size=10),
        plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
p1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code renamed the scale for the colour to `Task:` but left the shape scale name as `Condition`. Since they had different names ggplot added two legends.  You need to rename both shape and colour:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=dat,
             aes(x=Data, y=Estimate, group=Condition)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(11,15)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Condition, colour=Condition), size=3) +
  geom_errorbar(width=.12, linewidth=.5,aes(ymin=lo95CI, ymax=hi95CI, colour=Condition)) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette='Dark2') +
  labs(color="Task:", shape="Task:")+
  scale_x_continuous('Stimulus Type',
                     breaks=c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                     labels=c('T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4')) +
  scale_y_continuous('DV') +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14),
        legend.text=element_text(size=10),
        plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
p1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is, as explained by George, we have changed the name for colour but not shape. Adding my answer to simplify the code.

- we can rename the legend title using guides, instead of inside scale_
- keep all aes inside ggplot aes, then other geoms inherit relevant arguments.
- the x axis is "Type" not "Data". Use *Type* column with *position_dodge*. This will also remove the need for adding custom *scale_x_continuous* tick labels.
- keep limits within *scale_y_continuous*, *coord_cartesian* is for plotting with cropped data. In this case the data is within limits.

```r
ggplot(data = dat,
       aes(x = Type, y = Estimate, ymin = lo95CI, ymax = hi95CI,
           shape = Condition, colour = Condition)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.12, linewidth = 0.5, position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Stimulus Type") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "DV", limits = c(11, 15)) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "Task:"),
         shape = guide_legend(title = "Task:")) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title=element_text(size = 14),
        legend.text=element_text(size = 10),
        plot.title=element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]